# Look at last login and highlight if over a month ago

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview, datediff

I have a gridview, with a column that shows the last login date of a member. I wish to highlight this date if they haven't logged in for over a month.

I have

```
If DateDiff(DateInterval.Month, Now(), e.Row.Cells(10)) Then
        e.Row.Cells(10).BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red
    End If
```

Which of course, does not work. Any ideas please?

If you haven't guessed, kinda new to all this Visual Studio stuff!

Comment: you're just doing a diff without ever checking the RESULTS of that diff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example [`DateDiff()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/b5xbyt6f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) will return the number of months elapsed.

So the usage would be like this:

```
If DateDiff(DateInterval.Month, Now(), CDate(e.Row.Cells(10))) > 1 Then
    e.Row.Cells(10).BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red
End If
```

Also, see this [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311329) about `Option Strict` and `Option Explicit` I think `Option Strict On` might have caught this at compile time.

Comment: Thanks! The page will now preview, but doesn't work... I get the error "overload resolution failed because no accessible 'datediff' can be called with these arguments..."

Comment: This will be because e.Row.Cells(10) is not of type Date and DateDiff requires a value of type Date. Please see my edit (although, you should add some logic to check e.Row.Cells(10) can be converted into a Date type).